# How to run NegAIT with Stanford core nlp in Java in terminal in Mac?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, negation

I am not familiar with Java (only python). But I'd like to run [NegAIT.](https://github.com/gondyleroy/NegAIT)

I have stanford core nlp 3.7 installed & downloaded the [NegAIT repository](https://github.com/gondyleroy/NegAIT). They're both in my home directory. I also have JDK SE 1.8 set as my home path.

When I ran the command on my Macbook terminal inside the NegAIT-master folder:

```
java -cp negate.jar:/Users/username/NegAIT-master/stanford-corenlp-3.7.0/stanford-corenlp-3.7.0.jar:/Users/username/NegAIT-master/stanford-corenlp-3.7.0/stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models.jar negate.NegationParser AagenaesSyndrome.txt AagenaesSyndromeNegation
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP
    at negate.TextRead.<init>(TextRead.java:48)
    at negate.NegationParser.main(NegationParser.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

As I said, I am familiar with Python but not with Java, if someone could help me out or give me a tip on how to run this tool I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stanford CoreNLP is not being found on your CLASSPATH. It looks like that is because you haven't substituted your login name for `username` in the paths in the `-cp`.

Or, if you are in running the commend inside the `NegAIT-master` folder, and the CoreNLP jar files are in a subdirectory `stanford-corenlp-3.7.0` from there, you could simplify the CLASSPATH to:

```
java -cp negate.jar:stanford-corenlp-3.7.0/stanford-corenlp-3.7.0.jar:stanford-corenlp-3.7.0/stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models.jar negate.NegationParser AagenaesSyndrome.txt AagenaesSyndromeNegation
```